# Opening page from javascript is not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a login using `js`, I know this isn't secure it's just for school - they require it.

If username and password are correct I want it to open my photos page, this isn't happening.

As far as I can tell everything else is working just fine, it collects and compares data correctly, but won't open the new page. I have tried variations on the `this.location.href` such as `window.location` and `location.replace`.

I have also tried changing the `URL` using **full URL** and **photos.php**

The function is called from a click within the `HTML` :

```
<button type="submit" onclick="checkPassword()" class="button">Login</button>
```

This is the JavaScript:

```
function check() {   //onclick
    var username = "test";
    var password = "admin";
    var usernameEntered = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var passwordEntered = document.getElementById("password").value;

    if (usernameEntered == username && passwordEntered == password) {
        this.location.href = "http://localhost/photos-v4/photos.php";
    } else {
        alert("Incorrect username or password");
    }
}
```

Comment: window.location.href

Comment: When you say it won't work isn't there an error in console that says `"cannot read property location of undefined"` ?

Comment: See the above comments and also look into `window.open('http://www.google.com');`

Comment: @Adelin No, it just refreshes the page

Comment: @GeorgeBailey that's not working neither is window.location.href

Comment: Does that link open when you hit it directly through browser?

Anyway window.location.href is correct, because you are calling that method on onclick event, so 'this' would contain reference of the element on which you are calling onclick method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the HTML.

`type = "submit"` is used to send the data to a new place meaning that the data isn't being captured by the JavaScript.

A solution to this is replacing `submit` with `reset`which clears the form and, lets the js get the data it needs.

You can read more about HTML buttons here: https://html.com/attributes/button-type/

Answer (score 1):

Here a some ways to do it

## Open in new page

```
window.open('http://localhost/photos-v4/photos.php', '_blank').location;
```

## Open in the current tag

```
window.location.href = 'http://localhost/photos-v4/photos.php'
```

Comment: window.open() works but it opens in a new tab, even without '_blank'. Is there a way I can open it in the same tab?

Comment: Use `window.location.href`